# At what phase in rendering does clipping occur?

Tags: optimization, opengl

I've got some OpenGL drawing code that I'm trying to optimize.  It's currently testing all drawing objects for visibility client-side before deciding whether or not to send rendering data to OpenGL. (This is easier than it sounds.  It's drawing a 2D scene so clipping is trivial: just test against the current coordinates of the viewport rectangle.)

It occurs to me that the entire model could be greatly simplified by passing the entire scene to OpenGL and letting the GPU take care of the clipping.  But sometimes the total can be very, very complex, involving up to 100,000 total sprites, most of which never get rendered because they're off-camera, and I'd prefer to not end up killing the framerate in the name of simplicity.

I'm using OpenGL 2.0, and I've got a pretty simple vertex shader and a much more complicated fragment shader.  Is there any guarantee that says that if the vertex shader runs and determines coordinates that are completely off-camera for all vertices of a polygon, that a clipping test will be applied somewhere between there and the fragment shader and prevent the fragment shader from ever running for that polygon?  And if so, is this automatic or is there something I need to do to enable it?  I've looked around online for information on this but I haven't found anything conclusive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clipping and culling happen before fragment processing. http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview

However, you will still be passing 100000 * 4 vertices (assuming you're rendering the sprites with quads and not point sprites) to the card if you don't do culling yourself. Depending on the card's memory performance this can be an issue.

Comment: The general idea is that the vast majority of sprites (over 99%) are tiles in a tile map that never changes unless you switch to a different level.  If I upload the vertex data to VBOs I can do it once for the whole map and be done with it, instead of having to compute and send an entire screen's worth once per frame.  This would take a few MB of VRAM, but not all that much.

Answer (score 5):

Clipping happens after the vertex transform stage before and after the NDC space; *clip planes* are applied in clip space, viewport clipping is done in NDC space. That is one step before rasterizing. Clipping means, that a face only partially visible is "cut" by inserting new vertices at the visibility border, or fragments outside the viewport discarded. What you mean is usually called culling. Faces completely outside the viewport are culled, at the same stage like clipping.

From a performance point of view, the best code is code never executed, and the best data is data never accessed. So in your case sending off a single drawing call that makes the GPU process a large batch of vertices clearly takes load off the CPU, but it consumes GPU processing power. Culling those vertices before sending the drawing command consumes CPU power, but takes load off the GPU. The goal is to find the right balance. If the number of vertices is low, a simple brute force approach (just render the whole thing) may easily outperform ever other scheme.

However using a simple, yet effective data management scheme can greatly improve performance on both ends. For example a spatial subdivision structure like a Kd tree is easily built (you don't have to balance it). Sorting the vertices into the Kd tree you can omit (cull) large portions of the tree if one branch near to the root is completely outside the viewport. Preparing drawing a frame you iterate through the visible parts of the tree, building the list of vertices to draw, then you pass this list to the rendering command. Kd trees can be traversed on average in O(n log n) time.

Comment: Interesting idea.  I'll have to look into it.

Comment: Technically, clipping is done in (homogeneous) clipping coordinate space (CCS). Clipping in the projected NDCS will not produce correct results for interpolated vertex attributes.

Comment: @BrettHale: Yes and no. Yes if we're talking about clipping on the clipping planes, no if we're talking about viewport clipping. Modern implementations do viewport clipping in NDC for that it's simpler to compute. As long as the visible result is consistent with the result of plane based clipping this is a reasonable design choice. Also see http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut05%20Boundaries%20and%20Clipping.html#d0e5431

Comment: @datenwolf But is clipping done before or after (occlusion) culling?

Comment: @Nikos: Occlusion culling is not implemented by the GPU but by a clever combination of occlusion queries and drawing proxy geometry. Occlusion culling is implemented by drawing a (very simple) proxy geometry that fully wraps the geometry to be occlusion culled without actually drawing pixels/fragments to the framebuffer, and counting how many of them would actually "make it". If none do, the geometry proper is culled. Naturally the occlusion query count is after every other step, including clipping.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to understand the difference between *clipping* and *culling*. You appear to be talking about the latter.

Clipping means taking a triangle and literally cutting it into pieces to fit into the viewport. The OpenGL specification defines this process to happen post-vertex shader, for any triangle that is only partially in view.

Culling means throwing something away entirely. If a triangle is not entirely in view, it can therefore be culled. OpenGL does not say that culling has to happen. Remember: the OpenGL specification defines behavior, not performance.

That being said, hardware makers are not stupid. Obvious efforts like not rasterizing triangles that are outside of the viewport are easily implemented and improve performance. Pretty much any hardware that exists will do this.

Similarly, clipping is typically implemented (where possible) with rasterizer tricks, rather than by creating new triangles. Fragments that would be outside of the viewport simply aren't generated by the rasterizer. This is also legal according to OpenGL, because the spec defines *apparent* behavior. It doesn't really care if you actually cut the triangle into pieces as long as it looks indistinguishable form if you did.

Your question is essentially one of, "How much work should I do to not render off-screen objects?" That really depends on what your scene is and how you're rendering it. You say you're rendering 100,000 sprites. Are you making 100,000 draw calls, or are these sprites part of larger structures that you render with larger granularity? Do you stream the vertex data to the GPU every frame, or is the vertex data static?

Comment: Your last question is the impetus for my question.  A very large percentage of the data in question is static.  If I have a guarantee that *culling* happens before fragment processing, then I can stream it to a VBO once and not have to worry about it ever again.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Except that it's not _free_. You still have to transform those vertices. You still have to run the vertex shader on all of them. If you can cull groups of tiles on the CPU, then you'll get faster performance. You don't have to draw the entire tilemap in one draw call; you can split it up into chunks and cull based on those.

Comment: Right.  It just seems to me that I could replace a huge percentage of the current CPU-side drawing logic with a vertex shader that does all the same things, but much faster due to the GPU's massively parallel nature. If I could accomplish that efficiently, I think it would be good enough for my needs.